# View incoming requests log in console with Gunicorn and Flask

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

It's possible to view incoming requests with flask after launching it e.g.
[flask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z47jF.png)

Is there a way of viewing requests coming in live with gunicorn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run Gunicorn in the way below, you will see the incoming request log:

```
$ gunicorn --workers 3 your_module:your_app --access-logfile -
```